# Lua FIFO / QUEUE file

Tags: lua, embedded, iot, openwrt

I'm quite new to Lua and Embedded programming. I'm working on a project:

IoT node that can be abstractedinto two parts: sensor and a board that runs Open WRT with Lua 5.1. I'm writing script that would be called from crontab every minute.

1. In my script I'm accessing data from the sensor via package written with C. The result of reading data from sensor is 'hexadecimal numbers returned in string:

---

```
4169999a4180cccd41c9851f424847ae4508e0003ddb22d141700000418e666641c87ae14248147b450800003dc8b439
```

2. Then convert it (string) to values I need and POST it to API.

**Problem:**

Sometimes API is not reachable due to poor network connection.
So I need to implement system where I would read a data from a sensor and then if API is not responding, I would save it to a FIFO queue (buffer). And then next time when script is called to read it would be sending 'old' records first and the newest one and the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local queue_filespec = [[/path/to/your/queue/file]]
-- Initially your "queue file" (regular file!) must contain single line:
-- return {}

local function operation_with_queue(func)
  local queue = dofile(queue_filespec)
  local result = func(queue)
  for k, v in ipairs(queue) do
    queue[k] = ("%q,\n"):format(v)
  end
  table.insert(queue, "}\n")
  queue[0] = "return {\n"
  queue = table.concat(queue, "", 0)
  local f = assert(io.open(queue_filespec, "w"))
  f:write(queue)
  f:close()
  return result
end

function add_to_queue(some_data)
  operation_with_queue(
    function(queue)
      table.insert(queue, some_data)
    end
  )
end

function extract_from_queue()
  -- returns nil if queue is empty
  return operation_with_queue(
    function(queue)
      return table.remove(queue, 1)
    end
  )
end
```

Usage example:

```
add_to_queue(42)
add_to_queue("Hello")
print(extract_from_queue()) --> 42
print(extract_from_queue()) --> Hello
print(extract_from_queue()) --> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't think this would work out for me. I need to keep those records somewhere in file, because my script is called periodically (every minute) and as far as I concerned each time that script runs from scratch (it declares and creates all the variables with default values)

Comment: Thanks for  updating code. But I'm not sure what you mean by saying 'regular file', can I use binary file (buffer.bin)? I tried your script in interactive mode on my board and the very first call for a `add_to_queue(42)` gave me following error: `queue.lua:23: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)`

Comment: You must create your file and manually write the line `return {}` to it before running the program.  "Regular file" means "not a special file (such as pipe, socket, device,...)".  This file will store only text data, but you can give it any name you like, including "buffer.bin"  :-)